# How to use sigmoid function to normalized a list of vaues

Tags: python, normalization

I have a list of 516 numbers. These numbers range from 0 to 136661043272.12181 and they are not evenly distributed in this range. Now I want to normalize these numbers to [0,1] and I want to use the sigmoid function, i.e., original 0 will become 0 and original 136661043272.12181 will become 1. I know sigmoid function but my problem is that I don't know how to map original values to the exponent of e. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: First normalize dividing by 136661043272.12181, then use sigmoid.

Answer (score 4):

You use the [`exp` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp) from the `math` module:

```
import math
listMax = float(max(alist))
alist = [i/listMax for i in alist]
alist = [1/(1+math.exp(-i)) for i in alist]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but following this code will we get a range [0.5,0.7311] because the first alist will return values in range [0,1], but in my case, if I want the final range to be [0,1], then the range of first alist should be [-inf, +inf]

Comment: You can't have y=1 except in the limit as x tends to infinity. Are you sure you want a sigmoid? Why not use a saturating cubic, maybe one that approximates a shifted tanh(x) via the Taylor series if you want the output range to be 0 to 1?

Comment: Also, you can normalise the list to a value greater than 1 if you want to be  closer to the range 0 to 1

Comment: thank you very much. Maybe I will try your suggested methods and see whether I can come up with more interesting ideas.